# Regular Expression capturing records PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string

I need to capture the ZAMM records  of my string.
When you have space I can not capture data that belong to it.

My string:

```
$string ='ZAMM Et a est hac pid pid sit amet, lacus nisi
ZPPP scelerisque sagittis montes, porttitor ut arcu
ZAMM tincidunt cursus eu amet nunc
ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet, 
ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut';
```

expected return:

```
ZAMM Et a est hac pid pid sit amet, lacus nisi
ZAMM tincidunt cursus eu amet nunc
ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet,
```

I'm using:

```
$arrayst    = explode(" ", $string);

foreach($arrayst as $stringit) { 

    if(preg_match("/ZAMM.*/", $stringit, $matches)) {
       echo $stringit;
       echo "<br />";
    }

}

// Return:
ZAMM
arcu ZAMM
nunc ZAMM
```

I'm using the wrong regular expression?

**EDIT**: The last question.
If my string was like this:

```
$string ='ZAMM Et a est hac pid pid sit amet, lacus nisi ZPPP scelerisque sagittis montes, porttitor ut arcu            ZAMM tincidunt cursus eu amet nunc           ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet, ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your regex, it's with your `explode(" ", $string)`.  When you do this you are splitting the string to in an array of words.  You don't want that!  You want the regex to operate on the *entire* string, not on each individual word.

Actually, what you want is the regex to operate on each line in your string.

```
$string ='ZAMM Et a est hac pid pid sit amet, lacus nisi
ZPPP scelerisque sagittis montes, porttitor ut arcu
ZAMM tincidunt cursus eu amet nunc
ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet, 
ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut';

if(preg_match_all("/ZAMM.*/", $string, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[0] as $match){
        echo $match;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/BQIfkY

Comment: You could do with multiline mode and at least a start-of-subject assertion, this would also match rows with `ZAMM` in the middle ;-) but in general +1

Comment: @DaveRandom: I read your answer and realized that was a better solution.  I tried using `^$` and it wasn't working, forgot about the `m` flag :-D

Comment: @AmmWeb: No problem, that's why I'm here! :-D

Comment: @AmmWeb: You mean without newlines?  That's gonna be a bit of a challenge.

Comment: yes, no line breaks. I'm trying here too, if I can post the result.

Comment: @AmmWeb: Using a regex on a string without any delimiters (like new lines or commas) is complicated.

Comment: but I could capture them and go to the end of string? Ex. return **1 -** ZAMM Et a est hac pid pid sit amet, lacus nisi ZPPP scelerisque sagittis montes, porttitor ut arcu            ZAMM tincidunt cursus eu amet nunc           ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet, ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut **2 -** ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet, ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut

Answer (score 5):

For this you will want to use a regular expression in multiline mode, so you would use the `m` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), and look at an entire line of data.

Firstly we look for the start of a line and the data you want at the beginning of the line:

```
^ZAMM
```

...then we look for any data that is not a new line:

```
.+
```

We are able to use `.` here because it doesn't match new lines unless you also specify the `s` modifier, which we won't be doing. Next we assert the end of a line:

```
$
```

Put that all together and you get:

```
/^ZAMM.+$/m
```

Use it in PHP:

```
$string ='ZAMM Et a est hac pid pid sit amet, lacus nisi
ZPPP scelerisque sagittis montes, porttitor ut arcu
ZAMM tincidunt cursus eu amet nunc
ZAMM c ac nunc, et pid pellentesque amet, 
ZSSS m urna scelerisque in vut';

preg_match_all('/^ZAMM.+$/m', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WbgBqW)

Answer (score 1):

i changed this -> `$arrayst = explode(" ", $string);` to this -> `$arrayst = explode("\n", $string);` because in your string there are `\n`(line breaks) also, it's just my opinion, but you should put after every line `\n` (linebreak)